# Webform module - Contact form will not send webform emails to users with the same domain, but will send to all other email accounts I set

Tags: 6, webforms, emails

I have a Drupal 6 site. Using the Webform module.

I have it set to send all submissions to the webform to my email address (me@gmail.com) and the clients email (tim@domain.com) - for some reason webform is not sending the email to tim@domain.com only to my email address.

I tried different variations of emails, using other email addresses associated with the clients domain i.e. sales@domain.com but none of them work. But when I use other gmail and yahoo emails, the results come through just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: has your client checked their spam folder?

Comment: yes, I have access to their email and I triple checked the spam folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using a shared hosting?  Could be that the recipients mail server is thinking your mails are junk if the originating mail is not coming from the resolved hostname.  This problem is common with shared hosting since they use virtual hosts.

Comment: Hmm that is highly possible - I am using Hostgator VPS hosting. Unfortunately server wise I am a little inept - could you point me in a direction to resolve this one?

Comment: I would contact hostgator about this one.  It makes things much easier if you have a dedicated IP address for your domain.  Things get all wonky when you are having multiple domain names resolve to one single IP address.