# Module Webform won't send email to certain address

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

For some reason the **normal** contact form won't work. It doesn't send any mail to any address I request. 
Therefore, I used the module Webform for Drupal 7.

The problem I have is almost the same described in [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19467/webform-module-contact-form-will-not-send-webform-emails-to-users-with-the-sam).

However, for me the problem is even when the domain name is the same.  Like `user1@domain.com` works, but `info@domain.com` doesn't.

When I do send to a gmail account, there also is no problem.
Basically, the `info@domain.com` doesn't seem to be 'supported'.
All the other email addresses do work.

The domain-email is hosted by Gmail. (A Google Business account)

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it is that way? I could bet that it's the other problem - some clients' servers will simply refuse your emails, but all are sent. That's what always happened to me when I had similar outcome.

Comment: I prefer the SMTP module https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp to connect to Google and handle mails from there. Since then all messages arrived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this problem occurs because the mail is sent to the same server as the mail is sent from. The server itself thinks it is smart enough to handle this itself. This means de mail message is never 'leaving' the server. So, it'll never reach de gmail services.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue. I contacted my host (Hostmonster) and found that there is a setting in your Zone Editor that can fix this issue.

Under MX (Mail Exchanger) I selected Remote Mail Exchanger and under the section that says "Points to" I put exchange.domain.com (replace domain with your domain name). I did this because we are running all of our email through an exchange server.

Try calling your host and explaining the problem.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found out that this problem occurs because the mail is sent to the same server as the mail is sent from. The server itself thinks it is smart enough to handle this itself. This means de mail message is never 'leaving' the server. So, it'll never reach de gmail services.

Comment: Changing to "Remote Mail Exchanger" in that setting in cpanel fixed a similar issue for me.